# Is there a way to get the closest date to another date?

Tags: sql, time

I am trying to pull the type of fruit, the date of expiration, and the date it was last checked on. I need to pull the information of if the fruit was checked within 30 days before expiration or 5 days after expiration. The fruit is apples and bananas. So I have a customer fruit profile listing different fruits they have picked up. The table looks something like this:

| CustomerID | Fruit | Lastchecked | Expiration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Apple | 9/27/2023 | 10/05/2023 |
| 00001 | Banana | 9/30/2023 | 10/05/2023 |

My question is there a way to pick the closest either Apple or Banana last checked date to the newest expiration date? When I am pulling the information into a table it lists, if the person has it, two fruits which one would be an Apple and another one would be a Banana, I just need whichever fruit is the closest the last checked date to the expiration date, so the person is not counted twice in having or not having a date close enough. I thought using the 'BetweenTheRange' I created using the MAX function would pick up the closest date but when checking over the data I noticed some customers who should have been marked as a 1 from the 'BetweenTheRange' was not. I saw the incorrect marking in mostly customers who had a last checked date and an expiration date on the same day. For the date filter I am using the 'expiration date'

Here is some of the SQL:

```
SELECT Distinct
   "CUSTOMERPROFILE"."ExpirationDate",
   "CUSTOMERPROFILE"."LastCheckedDate",
   "CUSTOMERPROFILE"."CUSTOMERID",
CASE WHEN "CUSTOMERPROFILE"."LastCheckedDate" BETWEEN dateadd(d,-30,"CUSTOMERPROFILE"."ExpirationDate") and dateadd(d,5,"CUSTOMERPROFILE"."ExpirationDate") then 1 end AS BetweenTheRange
FROM "dbo"."CUSTOMERPROFILE" AS "CUSTOMERPROFILE"
WHERE "CUSTOMERPROFILE"."FruitType" = 'Apple' OR 'Banana'
```

I thought using the 'BetweenTheRange' I created using the MAX function would pick up the closest date but when checking over the data I noticed some customers who should have been marked as a 1 from the 'BetweenTheRange' was not. I saw the incorrect marking in mostly customers who had a last checked date and an expiration date on the same day.

**The fruit column is not actually in my query, its only in there for a filter. I just showed the column above so people could see what I am working with.**

Comment: 1) Which database are you using? Date handling is different between databases. 2) What type is `ExpirationDate` and `LastCheckedDate`? 3) Giving us a sample schema, sample data, and the results you want would be best. Then we'll have SQL we can execute and results we can replicate. Ideally set it up on a site like [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: I agree in all points with Schwern., Tag the request with your DBMS. We need this in order to know the features and syntax. Is this SQL Server? Then, is there one row per customer and fruit in the table or can there be multiple rows for one customer and one fruit? Please show sample data of, say, five rows and the result you expect, so we see what you are after.

Comment: Yes you can calculate the closest last checked date when compared to the newest expiration date. BUT every database vendor has different syntax, especially with dates, so until you tell us WHICH DATABASE we can't provide a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly clear on your needs, and I cannot make a comment due to lack of reputation points on this site.  I genuinely tried to understand the request and take it that you want the fruit by customer that has the least days between the last checked and expiration.

```
-- create and store some test data
declare @customer_fruit_check table
(
    customer_id varchar(10) not null,
    fruit varchar(255) not null,
    last_checked date not null,
    expiration date not null
)

insert into @customer_fruit_check
select '00001', 'apple', '2023-09-27', '2023-10-05' union all
select '00001', 'banana', '2023-09-30', '2023-10-05' union all
select '00002', 'apple', '2023-09-29', '2023-10-03' union all
select '00002', 'banana', '2023-09-29', '2023-10-04' union all
select '00003', 'apple', '2023-09-24', '2023-10-01' union all
select '00003', 'banana', '2023-09-27', '2023-10-05' union all
select '00004', 'apple', '2023-09-28', '2023-10-05' union all
select '00004', 'banana', '2023-09-26', '2023-10-03' union all
select '00005', 'apple', '2023-09-27', '2023-10-03' union all
select '00005', 'banana', '2023-09-29', '2023-10-07' union all
select '00006', 'apple', '2023-09-24', '2023-09-30' union all
select '00006', 'banana', '2023-09-30', '2023-10-05' 


-- output the test data exactly as it is for comparison purposes
select  c.customer_id,
        c.fruit,
        c.last_checked,
        c.expiration,
        datediff(day, c.last_checked, c.expiration) as days_remaining_until_expiration
from    @customer_fruit_check c
order by    c.customer_id,
            c.fruit

-- output what you need
select  top 1 with ties
        c.customer_id,
        c.fruit,
        c.last_checked,
        c.expiration,
        datediff(day, c.last_checked, c.expiration) as days_remaining_expiration
from    @customer_fruit_check c
order by    row_number() over (partition by c.customer_id order by datediff(day, c.last_checked, c.expiration))
```

[image]